# write to .json file without node.js

Tags: javascript, json

I have an item called result, where result is a .JSON object:

```
    {
         "id": "1345",
         "day": "Tuesday",
         "title": "Economics210"

     }
```

Is there a way to save this to a .json file in Javascript without `var fs = require('fs')` (Node)? This is all I see on the S.O. questions so far.

Perhaps by converting to text, then .json? Any ideas?

Comment: Are you trying to accomplish this without file io? Copy paste is your only option. Or are you trying to achieve this in the browser?

Comment: JSON is just a text format. It can be written by any language or by hand.

Comment: @Dave file io is fine just so long as I don’t have to use node I guess?

Comment: hey there haxtar — we're just missing some context here — there's a practically unlimited number of ways to save a file using a computer — considering we know you cannot use `node`, we need to know what other means are available to you in whatever environment you're operating under — if you're writing a python script for example, you should save the text file with the python standard library for file io — if you're writing a script for a web browser, you might want to use ajax to save to a web server, or perhaps use `localStorage` to write to the user's disk

Comment: @ChaseMoskal so the json file and html file in which the JS script is being written are both hosted on the same server, in the same location. I just want a way to modify the json file in the location it’s in by basically overwriting it to include the contents of result. Hope that was clearer

Comment: @haxtar — okay, you are writing a browser script — browser pages are unable to directly interact with the server's filesystem — you are left with two primary options: (1) add functionality to the web server which can save files on behalf of the webpage (2) your page can save/load directly from `localStorage` — i'll post an answer to explain

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create a file in memory for user to download, not through server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3665115/create-a-file-in-memory-for-user-to-download-not-through-server)

Comment: @ChaseMoskal thanks for your comments, I appreciate you taking the time to clear things up

Answer (score 5, accepted):

to save a file from browser-based javascript, you've got three basic directions to go:

1. **add server functionality to save files**

   - you have to know how to add functionality to your web server
   - you have to implement ajax in your browser page, which would make a POST request to the server, asking to save the file
   - the server would then save the file
   - you can set up a web server to do this with `node`, `python`, and about a billion other programming languages and platforms
   - the benefit to this method, is that the server is truly updating the file for everyone to see the update
2. **use `localStorage` on the webpage**

   - localStorage is a way for webpages to save data to their users' disk
   - localStorage data is *not* shared between users — a user can only interact with their own localStorage data
   - you can save and load entire JSON files in localStorage
3. **allow the user to download the file from their browser**

   - this is totally different, literally a regular file download into the user's own "Downloads" folder
   - see this post which @JaredSmith found [stackoverflow.com: create a file in memory for user to download](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3665115/create-a-file-in-memory-for-user-to-download-not-through-server)

Comment: This does not answer the question. If you are going to say that the question itself is in some way "wrong" (and I wouldn't argue with you if you did) then explain why to the OP with your proposed alternative, not just offering it in lieu of answering the actual question.

Comment: My question wasn’t wrong because the premise of it was based on something I wasn’t even knowledgeable about, which @chasemoskal cleared up, actually.

Comment: Thanks @ChaseMoskal, I’m going to check this out right when I get the chance

Comment: added third possibility mentioned by @JaredSmith

Answer (score 2):

Replace "File content" with JSON.stringify(yourObj) and you will be able to download it.

You can read more there: [How to create a file and generate a download with Javascript in the Browser (without a server)](https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/189/how-to-create-a-file-and-generate-a-download-with-javascript-in-the-browser-without-a-server)

```
function download(filename, text) {
  var element = document.createElement('a');
  element.setAttribute('href', 'data:text/plain;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(text));
  element.setAttribute('download', filename);

  element.style.display = 'none';
  document.body.appendChild(element);

  element.click();

  document.body.removeChild(element);
}

// Start file download.
download("hello.json","File content");
```